# Word in word wall does not teach me the word and Arngeir won't point me to the next one

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

This is happening with the word at **Volskygge**. Conologically:

1. During my adventures I find the word wall located at Volskygge peak. I already have the first two words of the shout **Whirlwind Sprint**, and this wall should teach me the last one.
2. But it doesn't, I hear the music and the usual sounds but the word is never taught to me, also the dragon priest does not rise from his coffin (I shout him to force him do so).
3. I use a console command to teach me the last word of Whirlwind Sprint.
4. Later on, Arngeir tells me to go to Volskygge to find the word located in this nordic tomb.  I do so and the problem persists, so the quest (finding all shout walls) does not advance.

> I have tried unteaching me the shout (and then the last word)  but still the wall doesn't provide me the word. I have also tried waiting, reloading the game and using shouts against the wall.

P.D: I suppose the command `setstage` could help, but I need the code of the quest to be able to use it, which I have been unable to find. The quest is the one which points you to the different words, which is listed under the various objectives.

So the simplest solution could be completing that objective ("Find the word in Volskygge") through a console command, Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've found the code of the quest:


WICastMagic04

Comment: @Wouter: That's a different quest -- one given by a courier. The asker is talking about [this quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Words_of_Power).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the console command `SetStage FreeFormHighHrothgarA 20` to fix this and advance the quest.

Source: [UESP Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Words_of_Power)

Comment: I have tried the command and doesn't finish the quest. Arngeir does not guide me to the next word.

Comment: @D1X Yikes, you're right -- wrong quest! Try `SetStage FreeFormHighHrothgarA 20` instead. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a console player (PS3), the only way I once fixed this was to save the game in front of the wall, fast travel elsewhere then load that save.